# 2002 Lexus IS300 wagon rear door will not stay open

Tags: lexus

When I lift the rear wagon door, I have to hold it up to keep it from falling. How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the liftgate supports. These are the relatively thin piston rods which are attached between the door and the body. These are fairly easy to replace and can be bought at most auto parts stores.

This is what the part looks like:

[image]

Comment: Always replace them in pairs. Replacing just one will hold the lift gate open but will fail quickly due to it holding twice the designed weight.